# Clicakble planets

Tags: javascript, mouse, onmousedown

Im trying to make planets that give an alert message when clicked.
Problem is, onmousedown only works on canvas, as far I tested.
Code for planets:

```
var planets = [];
for (var b=0;b<3;b++) {
planets.push(planet(0,360,Math.random()*600,Math.random()*600));
}

function planet(I,shiips,xpos,ypos){
I = I||{};
I.ships = shiips;
I.x=xpos;
I.y=ypos;
return I;
}
```

code for click detection; tests both for planet object and the image

```
update = function(){
planetImage.onmousedown=function(){alert("works!")};
planets[0].onmousedown=function(){alert("works!")};
}
setInterval(update,100);
```

Im using canvas to draw the images, if that hhelps.
I found the following code that gives mouse position, but it doesnt work for me:

```
(function() {
    var mousePos;

    window.onmousemove = handleMouseMove;
    setInterval(getMousePosition, 100); // setInterval repeats every X ms

    function handleMouseMove(event) {
        event = event || window.event; // IE-ism
        mousePos = {
            x: event.clientX,
            y: event.clientY
        };
    }

    function getMousePosition() {
        var pos = mousePos;
        if (!pos) {
            // We haven't seen any movement yet
        }
        else {
            // Use pos.x and pox.y
        }
    }
})();
```

Im trying to keep it simple, I don't really like jquery or anything complicated.
Once again: the problem is onmousedown only works on the canvas object, i.e.

```
canvas.onmousedown=function(){alert("works!")};
```

Comment: Have you tried comparing the mouse position in the canvas's mouseClick event to the positions of the planets?

Comment: _"Im trying to keep it simple, I don't really like jquery or anything complicated"_ - Used correctly, jQuery makes things _less_ complicated, not _more_ complicated. _Much_ less complicated for some purposes.

Comment: What's the result of `alert(planets.length);` ?

Comment: Probably 3, I made an initialization so at start 3 random planets are created

Answer (score 0):

I got it working now with this code:

```
update = function(){
canvas.onmousedown=function(){
var e = window.event;
var posX = e.clientX;
var posY = e.clientY;
alert("X position: "+ posX + " Y position: " + posY);
};
setInterval(update,100);
```